# How to change subscriber affiliation without owner intervention with XMPP PubSub

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

I am using XMPP Pubsub (XEP-0060). My application has the following requirements:

1. Users can create pubsub nodes: This is working fine.
2. Users can subscribe to already created nodes and automatically become publishers without owner intervention. I am in a situation where I need everybody on the node to be both a publisher and subscriber.

The problem I have is that after I subscribe a new user to the PubSub node, they have a "none" affiliation by default. There is no way to change the affiliation from my client application as the only the owner can change affiliations.

Am I missing a setting in the [XEP-0060](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) that can help achieve this behavior?

Comment: Which XMPP server are you using ?

Comment: I am using openfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the client that create the node, you can consider looking into the `publish_model` option of the PubSub node.

The default `publish_model` is `publishers`, but there are other options available such as `subscribers` and `open`. Setting the `publish_model` option of your PubSub node to `subscribers` should help you achieve what you need.

Depending on the actual XMPP server you are using, the feature may or may not be available. It should work with ejabberd latest version configured to use node type `hometree`.

Comment: I am using openfire ,I just checked in the features advertised by the server and found  the feature ' <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-and-configure"/> ' advertised ,I m going to try and set the publish_modes to **subscribers** and how it turns out.

Comment: Setting the publish_modes to subscribers solved my problem as you said. Thank you.By the way ,Where are these publish modes documented in the XEP0060?I scanned it and could not find a reference to them.

Comment: They are not documented but mostly listed in the node configuration.